# How to source control Elasticsearch

Tags: asp.net, windows, git, elasticsearch

I'm just starting work on a website which I want to integrate [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) into. In my development environment, I will need to install ES so that I and other devs can quickly get started with minimum effort.

We're using ASP.NET for the website (so I know all the devs will be running the website on Windows) and Git for source control.

Previously, on a another project, I have followed the [installation guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/windows.html) and simply source controlled the following folders in ES:

- /bin/
- /config/
- /lib/
- /modules/

*please note, the above folders were for ES 2.x so may slightly differ from 5.x*

I then created a simple `.bat` file which devs run when they start working on the project:

```
cd %~dp0\elastic\bin\
start elasticsearch

cd %~dp0
```

All the script does is run ES.

However, I wonder if I should even be source controlling these files. Perhaps it would be better if I had a `.bat` file which would download a fresh copy of ES when a developer starts work?

Comment: did you add elasticsearch files into your source files and commit it to source controller?

Comment: I have previously source controlled ES folders such as the `/bin/` folder before, but this may be adding unnecessary weight to my git repo.

Comment: You can use docker or vagrant configuration? You should not add Elasticsearch to your source.

Comment: For PHP Example you can check this repo: https://github.com/hkulekci/es5-devnot.

Comment: Hmm I was slightly trying to avoid using Docker because it's another tool which everyone has to install. However, I'm giving it a shot. Thanks for the repo!

Comment: Hmm, you are right, I gives another tool to your project but you should separate the environments because The technologies such as Elasticssearch, Redis, etc. are your project dependencies. This is a choice. On the other hand, I think, `.bat` file is a solution if all of your development environment is windows and it won't change. But for this solution, you can not add the ES files to your source, your `.bat` file check the files and it should install ES if ES is not installed, as you said above.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of issues trying to use Docker right now.. I think I will just have to install Elasticsearch normally for now and use a `.bat` file as we've mentioned. Thanks for the help.